# MacOS: How to disable Bluetooth while the computer is asleep (lid is closed)?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have two Macbook Airs (one for work + one for personal) and it drives me crazy when my closed, supposedly asleep Macbook autoconnects to my bluetooth headphones before I have a chance to connect them to a different device. How can I makes my computer *not* autoconnect to Bluetooth devices while it's asleep? I don't see any built-in option to disable this.

Comment: For some unknown reason, in Monterey Apple removed the simple, obvious, useful switch that used to be in Bluetooth prefs.

Answer (score 4):

MacOS doesn't include a built-in option for this, but it's easy to wire together a couple Homebrew packages to achieve the same functionality. Here's the steps I used to set up a script which disables Bluetooth on sleep and re-enables it on wakeup (requires basic comfort with the terminal):

- Install Homebrew: https://brew.sh/
- `brew install sleepwatcher`
- `brew services start sleepwatcher` (A MacOS dialog will prompt you for permission.)
- `brew install blueutil`
- Run `blueutil` to confirm that the utility has the needed MacOS permissions.
- Create `~/.sleep`, `~/.wakeup`, and `~/.sleepwatcher.log` content as shown below.
- Run `which blueutil` and confirm that the path matches the path used in the scripts below (or update the scripts accordingly)
- `chmod 700 ~/.sleep`
- `chmod 700 ~/.wakeup`

Then close the lid, wait a few seconds, open it again, and check `~/.sleepwatcher.log`.

Contents of the file `~/.sleep`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Sleepwatcher (Homebrew package) script that runs on sleep.
# See also: ~/.sleep, ~/.wakeup, ~/.sleepwatcher.log
/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power off
echo "$(date -Iseconds) -- Sleep event detected, bluetooth disabled. Bluetooth status: $(/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power)" >> ~/.sleepwatcher.log
```

Contents of the file `~/.wakeup`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Sleepwatcher (Homebrew package) script that runs on wakeup.
# See also: ~/.sleep, ~/.wakeup, ~/.sleepwatcher.log
/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power on
echo "$(date -Iseconds) -- Wake event detected, bluetooth enabled. Bluetooth status: $(/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power)" >> ~/.sleepwatcher.log
```

Contents of the file `~/.sleepwatcher.log`:

```
# Sleepwatcher activity log. See also ~/.wakeup and ~/.sleep scripts.
```

#### EDIT: Additionally disable wifi access while sleeping

The above can easily be extended to also disable connecting to wifi networks while asleep.

`~/.sleep`:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power off
/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
echo "$(date -Iseconds) -- Sleep event detected. Disabled bluetooth and wifi. Bluetooth status: $(/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power). $(/usr/sbin/networksetup -getairportpower en0)" >> ~/.sleepwatcher.log
```

`~/.wakeup`:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power on
/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
echo "$(date -Iseconds) -- Wake event detected. Enabled bluetooth and wifi. Bluetooth status: $(/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil --power). $(/usr/sbin/networksetup -getairportpower en0)" >> ~/.sleepwatcher.log
```

Comment: Folks should note that `sleepwatcher` requires the **Input Monitoring** permission which _"Allows the applications below to monitor the input from your keyboard even while using other applications._". While I'm not accusing `sleepwatcher` of doing anything malicious, there's a chance that inputs could be siphoned off to a third party by accident.

Answer (score 3):

[Bluesnooze](https://github.com/odlp/bluesnooze) seems to do the trick in a single package.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! Do you happen to know a comparable all-in-one package for disabling wifi when sleeping?